# How is the .__new__function working in this example?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, metaclass

I am having some trouble understanding how the .**new** magic method creates classes. Below is an example from an API I am using that uses metaclasses to dynamically create objects from information in a database.

```
class Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        print(f' cls - {cls}')
        print(f' name - {name}')
        print(f' bases - {bases}')
        return super(Metaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dict_)

class MyObject(object, metaclass=Metaclass):
    pass

class PrimaryObject(MyObject):
    pass

class SecondaryObject(MyObject):
    pass

test = PrimaryObject()
```

Running this code causes a PrimaryObject to be instantiated, which inherits from MyObject, which in turn inherits from the metaclass. The new magic method in the metaclass is then called, which iterates three times through all of the objects that inherit from the metaclass, even ones which weren't called:

```
<class '__main__.Metaclass'>
MyObject
(<class 'object'>,)
<class '__main__.Metaclass'>
PrimaryObject
(<class '__main__.MyObject'>,)
<class '__main__.Metaclass'>
SecondaryObject
(<class '__main__.MyObject'>,)
<__main__.PrimaryObject object at 0x000002214A6786D0>
```

How is the **new** method receiving these arguments, as nothing is passed to it? Are they parsed from the object that is calling it? And if so, why and how is it iterating through other objects that inherit from the object but weren't instatiated (SecondaryObject)?

Thanks

Comment: It's a metaclass, it is invoked when the *class* is created not when *instances* are created.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think it'd be better to use the term "defined" instead of "created", ie "class is defined"

Comment: @DeepSpace not sure what makes it clearest, but an instance of the type class is being created at that point.

Comment: `MyObject` is an *instance* of `MetaClass`; look at the value of `type(MyObject)`, compared to something like `type(int)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...which in turn inherits from the metaclass..."

THis is the wrong part in your assumptions. 
None of those classes  "inherit" from the metaclass.

The metaclass is used to build them - the classes themselves - just once
for each class. That is when `__new__` is called: when Python executes the `class` statement (along with the class body).

Instantiating `PrimaryObject` won't call the metaclass  `__new__` anymore - just add another print statement there, before the `test = ...` line and you will see this.

however, if you want a method on the metaclass to be called when you create an instance of the classes created with the metaclass, that is the  `__call__` method, not `__new__`. When you call `super().__call__(...)` inside your metaclass call, it will run `type.__call__`, which in turn is what runs the class `__new__` and `__init__` methods, creating a new instance.

```py
print("defining the metaclass")

class Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        print(f' cls - {cls}')
        print(f' name - {name}')
        print(f' bases - {bases}')
        return super(Metaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dict_)
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        print(f"Creating a new instance of {cls.__name__}")
        return super().__call__(*args, **kw)

print("Creating the classes that use the metaclass")

class MyObject(object, metaclass=Metaclass):
    pass

class PrimaryObject(MyObject):
    pass

class SecondaryObject(MyObject):
    pass

print("Creating a class instance")

test = PrimaryObject()
```

Answer (score 0):

The metaclass is the type of a class. Given your code, compare

```
>>> type(MyObject)
<class '__main__.Metaclass'>
>>> type(int)
<class 'type'>
```

Ultimately, all metaclasses inherit from `type`.

---

A `class` statement is a construct used to make an implicit call to some metaclass.

```
# A = type('A', (), {})
class A:
    pass

# MyObject = Metaclass('MyObject', (), {})
class MyObject(metaclass=Metaclass):
    pass
```

[How the metaclass is chosen](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) is outlined in the Python language reference.

---

Like all types, a call to the type itself invokes a call to its `__new__` method, so

```
MyObject = Metaclass('MyObject', (), {})
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
MyObject = Metaclass.__new__(Metaclass, 'MyObject', (), {})
if isinstance(MyObject, Metaclass):
    MyObject.__init__()
```